# Use '$d(x,y)$= |$1\over x$ - $1\over y$| is topologically equivalent to standard metric on (0, 1)' to show boundedness is not a topological property

Tags: general-topology

I believe that for boundedness to be a topological property then $d(x,y)$ having this property means the standard metric should too (It is already shown that these metric spaces are homeomorphic). I see that|$1\over x$ - $1\over y$| is bounded by properties of absolute values but how do I show that the standard/Euclidean metric does not follow suit (not bounded in effect)? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is the other way around: The standard (Euclidean) metric is bounded on $(0,1)$, but the metric $d(x, y)=|\frac 1x - \frac 1y|$ is unbounded.

Comment: "by definition boundedness is not a topological property" -- that is not by definition. Just because the _definition_ of boundedness mentions things other than the topology, one could conceivably imagine there were other equivalent characterizations that do work purely by topology. Consider for example that _among closed subsets of $\mathbb R$_, boundedness _is_ a topological property, since the ones that are bounded are exactly the compact ones.

Comment: @MartinR Ahh that makes sense, thank you for answering

Comment: @Troposphere I wasn't aware that it could be a topological property based on context so thank you for noticing that, I edited it out of my question

Comment: @user962766: It's not so much a question of "based on context", though I see that the example I picked could give that impression. A different example: For maps between metric spaces, _continuity_ is usually given an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition that appears to depend crucially on the metric. Continuity is nevertheless a topological property because we can _also_ characterize continuous maps in terms of just open sets, and that yields the _same_ class of maps.

Comment: In other words, whether a property is a topological depends only on _which things_ have the property, not on how we happen to have _defined_ the property.

Comment: @Troposphere That makes sense, so its based on properties shared between homeomorphic metric spaces?

Comment: Another way to show that boundedness is not a topological property: Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $d$ is unbounded. That is, $\sup_{u,v\in X}d(u,v)=\infty$. The metric $e(u,v)=\min (1, d(u.v))$ is equivalent to $d.$ That is, $e$ generates the same topology that $d$ does. But $X$ (and every subset of $X$) is $e$-bounded.

Comment: @user962766: Yes, exactly!

Comment: @DanielWainfleet May I ask how are the metrics in your example equivalent?

Comment: Metrics are called equivalent iff they generate the same topology. The set of open balls of radius less than $1$ is a base (basis) for the topology. For $d$ and $e$ this is the same set.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Okay, that makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your use of boundedness, I assume you mean a metric space $(X,d)$ is bounded if there exists a point $x \in X$ and a radius $M$ so that $X \subseteq B_d(x,M)$, the $d$-ball of radius $M$ centered at $x$. Clearly, $(0,1) \subseteq \{ x \in (0,1) : |x - 1/2| < 1 \}$. So $(0,1)$ is bounded with its standard metric.

However, let $x_0 \in (0,1)$ and $M > 0$ be arbitrary. We claim that $(0,1) \not\subseteq \left\{ x \in (0,1) : \left| \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0} \right| < M \right\}.$ Observe that $0 < M$ and $0 < x_0$ implies that $$0 < Mx_0 \implies 0 < x_0 < 1 < M x_0 + 1 \implies 0 < \dfrac{x_0}{1+Mx_0} < 1.$$ Let $x = \dfrac{x_0}{1+Mx_0}$ and behold that $$\left|\frac{1}{x_0} - \frac{1}{x}\right| = \left| \frac{1}{x_0} - \frac{1 + Mx_0}{x_0}\right| = M.$$ This establishes the claim that $(0,1)$ is not bounded with the metric $\left|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}\right|$.

In general, *every* metric is equivalent to a bounded metric. For example, let $\rho$ be any metric on a set $X$ and show that $\rho$ is compatible with $d(x,y) = \min\{1,\rho(x,y)\}$. As a particular example, this shows that $\mathbb R$ has a metric compatible with its standard Euclidean metric for which it is bounded.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but can you elaborate on 'every metric is equivalent to a bounded metric'

Comment: @user962766 Yes, what I mean by that is the sentence that follows that claim. You can take any metric and show that this minimum with 1 is a metric that produces the same topology. For example, let $d : \mathbb R^2 \to [0,\infty)$ be defined by $d(x,y) = \min\{1,|x-y|\}$. It's a straightforward exercise to show that $d$ produces the standard topology on $\mathbb R$ but now we have that $\mathbb R \subseteq B_d(0,2)$ so $\mathbb R$ is bounded with respect to $d$.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, thank you!